# How to print a WebView?

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-webview, google-cloud-print

My Android app renders a WebView containing a canvas. Cloud Print wants a PDF. How can I generate a PDF with my WebView to send to Cloud Print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first capture the canvas as a png: (taken from [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf))

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Then next step get this into a pdf. I haven't seen a javascript based converter, but one could send the png to a custom web service (perhaps running on Google Apps, Amazon AWS or a traditional hosted machine) which simple returns a pdf. ImageMagick could be used here with a wrapper cgi script or you could use some library. Alternatively it might be possible to do the conversion within the android app.

Comment: Well, it's not the miraculous solution I was hoping for, but I guess printing is just not easy in Android yet. Thanks for the pointer to the other answer, too -- `Canvas.toDataURL` looks intriguing.

Answer (score 0):

there is also WebView.capturePicture()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#capturePicture()